# Trigger parent property

Tags: vb.net, properties

How Can I update parent property? My example code below.

When Demo2 property (Class2) set a value, I want run code Demo property (Class1)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
'My example code
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Dim d As New Class1
      d.Demo.Demo2 = True ' Set value
   End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class1
   Dim c As Class2

   Public Sub New()
      c = New Class2
   End Sub


   Public Property Demo As Class2
      Get
         Return c
      End Get
      Set(value As Class2)
         '**How can I run this row?**
         c = value
      End Set
   End Property
End Class

Public Class Class2
   Private b As Boolean

   Public Property Demo2 As Boolean
      Get
         Return b
      End Get
      Set(value As Boolean)
         b = value
      End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Correctly tag the question with a target language/environment. As it is, it is unclear what language is being used.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you are having trouble with.